# Are my home keys compromised if I use a key duplication machine?

Tags: physical, credit-card, key

Given that if someone has physical access to your home keys for enough time to take a picture of them, [you've already lost](https://www.wired.com/2014/08/3d-printed-bump-keys/), what stops key duplication machines such as MinuteKey from taking pictures of all they keys they duplicate? MinuteKey in particular only takes credit cards, so it has your name and your important keys.

If a machine reads your credit card, can it get your billing address, which for most credit card users is often their home address?

Are there defenses against this besides using cash?

It seems like these machines would be attractive hacking targets.

Comment: Credit (and debit) card-present transactions do not provide the cardholder address. But if you drive there they can see the license plate on your car and in at least some US states they can get your address from that, if you use a cab or quasi-cab like Uber/Lyft they could almost certainly bribe or hack the driver, so you'd better walk. And even then they could follow you with drones, or possibly ninjas.

Answer (score 4):

Your home keys are compromised the second you let someone take a look at them. I recall [the story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_DeFriest#Prison_escapes) of a prisoner who made a copy of the warden's key himeself just by remembering how it looked.

For most this is an acceptable risk as lockpicking is a thing, and most doors can easily be taken down, so someone who wants to get in *will* get in.

If you deem the risk not acceptable, consider making your own electronic lock with PKI smart cards. The lock will give the card a random challenge and the card has to sign it with its private key. Thus replay attacks are foiled (where an attacker having access to the key generates a ton of signatures for later use) and copying is impossible as the private key can't be extracted.

Do not rely on those smart home "locks" which use wireless and mobile phone apps. Not only do they have a huge attack surface, designed by people who have more experience in marketing than in security, and they require you to have an app which you can't be sure how long they'll maintain. I consider those devices as toys for people to brag about how <s>smart</s> [stupid](https://twitter.com/internetofshit) their home is rather than proper security tools.

Of course with such a strong lock you should also think about replacing the door, otherwise you may find that your lock is all that remains of the door.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answers covered your question about key duplication machines, so I'll add something about credit cards.

An international standard, [ISO IEC 7813](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_7813), defines some characteristics of credit cards, including the data format.

Magnetic stripe cards contain two tracks, Track 1 and Track 2. Both contain data and both can be read by most credit card readers.

They contain the account number, name of the owner, expiration date, and other codes such as the service code. Moreover, they also include a DD (Discretionary Data) section, whose content and format specifications are left to the card issuing companies. Some of them use it as a padding, some of them store security codes like the CVV or CVC (Card Verification Value or Card Verification Code) on it, and so on.

While it is theoretically possible that the DD section may contain information about your address, this is unheard of and it cannot be easily checked. If you're interested, you could search on the Internet for documentation of the DD section written by your card issuing company, or you could try and reverse engineer the format yourself.

Answer (score -1):

You can make your own key duplicates if you are this paranoid.

Comment: I'm not paranoid, but it seems these machines are just too great honey pots.